# Schwinn Meridian Trike clicking

Tags: chain, tricycle, clicking, schwinn

So I just bought a bike for my first time as an adult, yay! More specifically I got a Schwinn Meridian trike. Just got it together yesterday and it rides fine but when I ride it or roll it forward it makes a clicking sound. Not super loud. The clicking appears to be coming from that little chain that goes between the front and back part of the frame. All the advice I found online about clicking chains is either for old chains or bikes with gears, neither of which applies here. I'm sorry I don't know the proper name for things. The rear sprockets the chain goes around seems to be just a hair off center. Could that be causing the click?